# Comparing multiple elements of a document embedded in an array which is a field in a collection, to one element

Tags: mongodb

I have a restaurant collection in which every document has an array called "grades" which stores "date","score","grade" as separate documents. What i want to do is select restaurants that were given a score better than 60 on all 4 dates. I am trying to come up with a query that will work with arrays that have n number of scores

```
I've tried this query: 
       db.r.find(
       {$nor:[{"grades.score":{$lt:50,$gt:90}}]},
       {_id:0,grades:1}
       ).limit(5).pretty();

{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5d92477d5a50e0f057174914"),

        "grades" : [
                {
                        "date" : ISODate("2014-09-06T00:00:00Z"),
                        "grade" : "A",
                        "score" : 2
                },
                {
                        "date" : ISODate("2013-07-22T00:00:00Z"),
                        "grade" : "A",
                        "score" : 11
                },
                {
                        "date" : ISODate("2012-07-31T00:00:00Z"),
                        "grade" : "A",
                        "score" : 12
                },
                {
                        "date" : ISODate("2011-12-29T00:00:00Z"),
                        "grade" : "A",
                        "score" : 12
                }
        ],
        "name" : "Dj Reynolds Pub And Restaurant",
        "restaurant_id" : "30191841"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no filter query to achieve this directly. Only thing you can do is to use aggregation framework and achieve your desired result. First you have to unwind the `grades` array, then you filter all the documents with `score` greater than 60, then group by `_id` along with that use `$push` re-create array of `grades`, then again use  `match` to filter only documents with `grades` array size of `n`.

Below query works for documents with n=4

```
[{
    $unwind: {
        path: "$grades"
    }
}, {
    $match: {
        "grades.age": {
            $gte: 60
        }
    }
}, {
    $group: {
        _id: "$_id",
        grades: {
            $push: "$grades"
        }
    }
}, {
    $match: {
        "grades": {
            $size: 4
        }
    }
}]
```